# How to adjust brush hardness

Tags: texture-painting

I'm using texture paint for the first time and I don't see any place to adjust the hardness of a brush. Do I have to create my own texture masks for the brushes?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try changing [Curve](https://www.blender.org/manual/ru/sculpt_paint/painting/texture_paint/tools.html#curve) in the brush's panel ?

Comment: Aha, it's  curve NOT hardness that I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In 2.8 it is called Falloff in the Brush options.